# How to create a new variable that is a conditional cumulative sum of another binary variable?

Tags: r, conditional-statements, cumsum

I'm cleaning up some eye-tracking data, which is, as expected, messy. I'm stuck on a preliminary step that I'll do my best to describe thoroughly. The solution is likely quite simple.

I've got two variables, one binary (`x1`) and the other continuous (`x2`), such as that created by:

```
dat <- data.frame(x1 = c(0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1), 
                  x2 = c(22,23,44,25,36,37,28,19,30,41))
```

I need to create a new variable (`x3`) that is the cumulative sum of x2 *only* for consecutive cases in which x1 is equal to 1. The end product would look like such:

```
dat <- data.frame(x1 = c(0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1), 
                  x2 = c(22,23,44,25,36,37,28,19,30,41), 
                  x3 = c(0, 23, 67, 0, 36, 73, 101, 0, 30, 71))
```

In other words, it's a `cumsum()` of `x2` that "resets" after each 0 in `x1`.

Comment: Why is the second x3 value equal to 44?

Comment: Oops--overlooked a mistake. I just fixed it. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
dat$x3 <- with(dat, ave(replace(x2, x1 == 0, 0), cumsum(x1 == 0), FUN=cumsum))

dat
#   x1 x2  x3
#1   0 22   0
#2   1 23  23
#3   1 44  67
#4   0 25   0
#5   1 36  36
#6   1 37  73
#7   1 28 101
#8   0 19   0
#9   1 30  30
#10  1 41  71
```

Comment: or variation: `transform(dat, x3 = ave(x2 * x1, cumsum(x1 == 0), FUN = cumsum))`

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks so much. Will add to my repertoire.

Answer (score 1):

In data.table, you could group by runs of x1 (using `by=rleid(x1)`) and then return 0 if the group of x1 is 0, or otherwise return the cumulative sum of x2. `:=` is used to assign the variable by reference.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, x3 := if(x1[1] == 0) 0 else cumsum(x2), by=rleid(x1)]
```

this returns

```
dat
    x1 x2  x3
 1:  0 22   0
 2:  1 23  23
 3:  1 44  67
 4:  0 25   0
 5:  1 36  36
 6:  1 37  73
 7:  1 28 101
 8:  0 19   0
 9:  1 30  30
10:  1 41  71
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!